# Format and cleanup imported JSON in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using a script to import JSON in Google Sheets through a function in a formula. After it is imported, I need to cleanup the text (sample included below) and reformat the cell to only include the value after *"3":*

In this case I want to extract/keep only "55" and delete all the rest of the text. Is it possible to do it in the same cell with combining (using **&** or equivalent) the existing formula, which is importing the JSON, with a formatting one?

```
"{\"1\":1,\"2\":2,\"3\":55,\"4\"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

=index(
ArrayFormula(
ifna(
regexextract(
split(AB2,"")
,"[0-9]+")))
,,7)

[image]

1. Split the string using \ as a separator. This makes a table.
2. Use regexextract (and arrayformula to go through this table and extract all the numbers)
3. Ifna prevents from error messages when no number is found
4. Index takes 7th element from the table.

If this structure is always the same (the same number of parameters in JSON, it should work.